# How to use auto_train in C++ with libSVM

Tags: c++, opencv, svm, libsvm

I'm trying to auto train my dataset using the libSVM's auto_train function.
Reading this page http://docs.opencv.org/modules/ml/doc/support_vector_machines.html
i tried with this code:

```
CvSVMParams params;
params.svm_type    = CvSVM::C_SVC;
params.kernel_type = CvSVM::RBF;
```

Because i wanted a RBF kernel.
And then:

```
CvSVM SVM;
SVM.train_auto(trainFINAL, labelsFinal, Mat(), Mat(), params, 10, ...
   CvSVM::get_default_grid(CvSVM::C), CvSVM::get_default_grid(CvSVM::GAMMA), ...
   CvSVM::get_default_grid(CvSVM::P), CvSVM::get_default_grid(CvSVM::NU), ...
   CvSVM::get_default_grid(CvSVM::COEF), CvSVM::get_default_grid(CvSVM::DEGREE), ...
   false);
```

After that i tried to plot the new parameters in this way:

```
CvSVMParams newParams = SVM.get_params();
cout << endl;
cout << "KERNEL   : " << newParams.kernel_type << endl;
cout << "SVM TYPE : " << newParams.svm_type << endl;
cout << "degree   : " << newParams.degree << endl;
cout << "gamma    : " << newParams.gamma << endl;
cout << "coef0    : " << newParams.coef0 << endl;
cout << "Cvalue   : " << newParams.C << endl;
cout << "p        : " << newParams.p << endl;
```

But i can't understand 2 things:

- first, why in the newParams.svm_type it returns to me 100 (i specified C-SVC, it should be 0)
- second, it's correct to plot the parameters in this way?

Answer (score 0):

"first, why in the newParams.svm_type it returns to me 100 (i specified C-SVC, it should be 0)"

OpenCV enumeration is slightly different from LibSVM's, see http://docs.opencv.org/ref/2.4/dd/d88/classCvSVM.html

C_SVC is 100 and the first type of SVM in OpenCV (as opposed to 0 in LibSVM).

"second, it's correct to plot the parameters in this way?"

I am not sure what you mean by "plot" the parameters but if you want to know whether or not newParams are optimized parameters, then yes they are.